# Push array of object instead of its value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var items = [{
    "name": "James",
    "gender": "boy"
}, {
    "name": "Sam",
    "gender": "boy"
}, {
    "name": "Alice",
    "gender": "girl"
}];
```

I want to add count for the gender into a array of object above. like for boy it's 2, and girl it's 1. I've done below part where it return the category.

```
var genderList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < items.length ; i++){
      if(genderList.indexOf(items[i].gender) < 0){
        genderList.push(items[i].gender);
       }
}
```

how can I produce the result like this?

```
[{"name":"boy","count":2},{"girl","count":1}]
```

Comment: The desired result isn't valid JS, because the "girl" part has a property name with no value (or value with no property name). Why wouldn't you just use `{"boy": 2, "girl": 1}` instead of an array?

Comment: I'm a little late to the game but hoping my comments will help you understand what's happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [array `.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to count values - I'd suggest getting output in a structure like `{"boy": 2, "girl": 1}` rather than the array of objects you showed, because it's simple and efficient to create, update, and read.

You could then convert it to the format you've shown:

```js
var items = [
  { "name": "James", "gender": "boy"},
  { "name": "Sam", "gender": "boy"},
  { "name": "Alice", "gender": "girl"}
];

var genderCount = items.reduce(function(a, c) {
  a[c.gender] = (a[c.gender]||0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(genderCount));

var asArray = Object.keys(genderCount).map(v => ({ name: v, count: genderCount[v] }));
console.log(JSON.stringify(asArray));
```

If you're not familiar with `.reduce()`, it does the same thing as the loop below, except without needing to create extra working variables in the current scope:

```js
var items = [
  { "name": "James", "gender": "boy"},
  { "name": "Sam", "gender": "boy"},
  { "name": "Alice", "gender": "girl"}
];

var genderCount = {}
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  genderCount[items[i].gender] = (genderCount[items[i].gender]||0) + 1;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(genderCount));

// then as above to get your array of objects output:
var asArray = Object.keys(genderCount).map(v => ({ name: v, count: genderCount[v] }));
console.log(JSON.stringify(asArray));
```

**NOTE:** In the above examples I'm using `JSON.stringify()` *only* to make it fit in the console on one line, it's not part of the counting/conversion process.

Comment: At `for` loop example, OP appears to expect an array of objects as result.

Comment: @guest271314 - I ended up adding that part to the second block after all. That format makes no sense to me, unless maybe it is going to be input to some graphing function or something like that, but it *is* what she asked for. Either way I think it is more efficient to create the intermediate `{"boy":2,"girl":1}` object first and then map it, rather than trying to find and update values in an array during the counting phase.

Comment: @Mellisa - I've used "a" for "accumulator" and "c" for "current value". I think it's readable for folks who are familiar with `.reduce()` because they're part of the standard `.reduce()` behaviour. If the function were long and complicated I might use `acc` and `val` or even `accumulator` and `currentVal`, but this is a one-liner plus return statement with no other local variables, so... (Some people use "p" for "previous" instead of "a", depending on context.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = [
  { "name": "T", "gender": "other"},
  { "name": "James", "gender": "boy"},
  { "name": "Sam", "gender": "boy"},
  { "name": "Alice", "gender": "girl"}
];
```

taking the previous item and comparing the gender type. If it exists we add 1, if doesn't then we create it and add 1.

```
var genderTypes = items.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  prev[cur.gender] = (prev[cur.gender]||0) + 1;
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log('genderTypes', genderTypes)
```

next we take the keys from the object and separate them out into gender and count

```
var separateNameAndCount = Object.keys(genderTypes).map(type => ({ name: type, count: genderTypes[type] }));

console.log('separateNameAndCount', separateNameAndCount)
```

finally we convert the object to json format

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(separateNameAndCount));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var items = [{
    "name": "James",
    "gender": "boy"
}, {
    "name": "Sam",
    "gender": "boy"
}, {
    "name": "Alice",
    "gender": "girl"
}];
var b=0,g=0;
items.map((item)=>(item.gender=="boy")?b++:g++);
var finalArray = [{"name":"boy","count":b},{"name":"girl","count":g}]
console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: If you're not doing anything with the return value from `.map()` you should be using `.forEach()`.

Comment: what if I have another kind of gender?this solution is not flexible.

Comment: You can manage this using `if else if ..` conditions instead of ternary operator.